# Set text box as filename

Tags: matlab

I have `audiowrite` where I want the value of a text box to be the `filename`.

My current code does not work, an error says the value of filename is invalid. Anyone know how I fix this?

```
audiowrite(handles.edit4,'String',y,Fs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the [`String`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_String) property of the text box using either `get(handles.edit4,'String')` or if you have R2014b or newer you can use `handles.edit4.String`

```
filename = get(handles.edit4, 'String');

% In case "String" is a cell array
if iscell(filename)
    filename = filename{1};
end

audiowrite(filename, y, Fs)
```

**Update**

If you want to add an extension such as `.mp3` you can simply use `strcat` to append the extension

```
audiowrite(strcat(filename, '.mp3'), y, Fs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am still receiving the error, The value of 'filename' is invalid. I have used your format (no errors in syntax), and the textbox tag is definitely 'edit4'.

Comment: @Paji.R What does `class(filename)` give you?

Comment: how can I find out? There is no error on `filename`, just audiowrite where it's saying the expected input is char

Comment: Can you try `audiowrite(filename{1}, y, Fs)`. Also you could just put `disp(class(filename))` in between the two lines in my answer.

Comment: adding the `{1}` to the class has made it work, thanks very much. Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: @Paji.R Updated my answer to make it work in that case. It's because the `String` property can either contain a cell array of strings or a character. The solution above should work either way.

Comment: Cheers. Quick question how can I add the string `.mp3` at the end of filename to save from typing it in everytime

Comment: @Paji.R Updated with an example of how to do that